# Multiple pieces of data attached to multiple states

Tags: users, forms

I want to have two fields attached to each state a user selects on a multiple select form field - they can select as many states as they want.

Each state will then have a text field and a date field attached to it.

How do I do this? I can can't figure out a way to make this data optional.

So basically it would go as follows:

State
textfield associated with state
date associated with state

and this, up to 50 times, but optional aside from one instance.

Comment: what have you tried so far?  are you using code to create the form? can you post some code.

Comment: Well, currently I've just got a multiple select field with the states. I was looking into fieldgroup multiple, but it doesn't seem to be easy to make multiple instances of that on the fly. I basically want a user to be able to click a button and get another instance of the three field group.

I'm not even sure where I'd get started with code for this - I'm trying to add fields to the user register form which will ultimately go on the user's profile (in a separate tab with all of the data per state, but only states selected by the user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was the [field collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module (alternatively, [multifield](https://drupal.org/project/multifield) can be used).

This allows you to create an unlimited amount of field collections, and served my purposes perfectly.